# Can a page event be persisted across a page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which, when a user clicks an icon, launches a second window to update some database entries. When the child window is opened, I'd like to attach an event to fire a callback function and update a field on the parent screen. At the moment, the javascript is similar to:

```
var child = window.open(URL);
child.name = reference; // used to store parameters about which field to update
$(child).on('unload', function() {
    var w = this.name.split(':');
    fieldUpdate(w[1],w[0]);
});
// also tried ...
// child.onbeforeunload = function...
// child.onunload = function...
// child.onclose = function...
```

The problem is that the child page, which is used elsewhere and cannot be changed, used an `<input type="submit"...>` to initiate the postback and update the database. The controller method then reloads the view, which, obviously, clears all the events. So the callback only gets called on the first update.

From my testing, the `onbeforeunload` gets called before the controller postback, the `onunload` gets called after, and the `onclose` doesn't get called at all when using the `submit`. In all cases, the `child.name` property persists into the reloaded page, but all events are cleared.

Is there any way that the parent window could set up an event (or reinstate it) so that the callback fired whenever the `submit` action occurred? I've tried playing around with setting a timeout callback, but there seem to be problems with getting/retaining the child window parameter.

---

Update:

For information, the method I wish to call is similar to (actual code has more error checking etc.):

```
fieldUpdate: function(fieldName, id) {
    $.post(
        baseURL + 'getField',
        $.param({id: id, name: name}, true),
        function(json) {
            $('#' + json.Values.name + json.Values.id).val(json.Values.count);
        }
    );
}
```

This is in answer to Julian's comment about using AJAX. As you can see, I already do, but it's how to trigger the call from the clicking of a 'submit' button in the child page that I'm having trouble with.

If I could modify the child page, this would be fairly easy, but, unfortunately, that's not an option as it would break too much other code.

Comment: You DEFINITELY should use AJAX!

Comment: @Julian - Hints where to start, please? Just Googling AJAX isn't very helpful. Note that, as stated, changing the child page is *NOT* an option.

Comment: With AJAX you create a HTTP request "invisible" in JavaScript and get the result (HTML, XML, JSON, images, ...) as a return value of the function. If this is an option for you (hopefully I understood your problem correctly) I'll post some code that will help you! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I know that use of AJAX. The postback that I want to trigger actually uses it to get a field value and fill it in on the parent screen. The problem is that I need to get the child page to trigger the parent's AJAX call when it updates. All events on the child page seem to get reset when it executes the form submit. As far as I can tell, the unload event set by the parent runs in the context of the parent and I can't see how to get the 'new' child context to reset (or persist) the unload event when the child page reloads. Simply setting a timeout and trying to reset it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah... You should change the `<input type="submit" />` to a regular button and submit the form yourself using AJAX. A regular submit involves a page reload. You want to avoid that and do everything using AJAX. This is what I meant :-)

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, but unfortunately lots of other code uses the child page and we don't want to have to test a significant rewrite!

Comment: Can you explain how the other code interacts with the "child page"? You could also rewrite only the child page once for AJAX calls. Then you won't have to rewrite everything but one page... I can't really imagine how your page works... Could you mage a small diagram (http://asciiflow.com) to describe how which pages interact with each others?

Comment: The interaction is actually quite minimal. The reason it cannot be changed is more political than anything else. The child page is the main interface to a document management system which is part of a large web application used by over 2000 employees. The DMS is used many parts of the system (20 at the last count) so any change would require a serious amount of testing. The feature to update the document count on the parent page is classified as a "nice to have", rather than even "essential", so doesn't provide enough justification for a rewrite and subsequent testing of the whole system.

Comment: It seems the only practical solution is to rewrite the `<input type="submit" ...>` elements of the child page as `<input type="button" ...>`, modify the controller methods (mainly change from  type `ActionResult` to `JsonResult`), insert AJAX calls and add an empty 'hook' function. The parent can then rewrite the child's 'hook' function completely reliably and nothing else that uses the page is affected.